# How to extract only the time from a list of date time

Tags: python

Here is my code to get date and time when starting time is 10 am,( (2017, 10, 29, 10, 0) and then date time until 10 am on the next day. Now, I want to extract only the time from that and get 10:00 am to 10 am on the following day .
So my result should be

```
(10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00,14:00,15:00,16:00,17:00,18:00,19:00,20:00,21:00,22:00,23:00,00:00,1:00,2:00,3:00,4:00,5:00,6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00,10:00)
```

I would be thankful if someone could assist me in this regard.

```
import datetime

a=datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(10))

x = [a + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(24)]
```

Comment: Do you want 10:00 am both days included, as shown in your example output? Your existing code won't achieve that. Also, what is the intended output format: instances of `datetime.time`, strings, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) method of the `datetime` class returns the "time" part of the date/time. Using it, you can achieve what you're after as follows:

```
times = [dt.time() for dt in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it a bit:

```
["{}:00".format((a + datetime.timedelta(hours=i)).hour) for i in range(24)]
                                                   ^
```

take only the `hour` from the datetime object and format it the way you want.

**OUTPUT**

```
['10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for response alfasin.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
x = [ ( (today + datetime.timedelta(hours=i)).hour ) for i in range(24)]
print(x)
```

each today plus i hour and get their attribute hour